# Event Report missing info

Tags: civievent

I set up an event and asked participants to answer a few questions.  How do I pull a report for my event with the answers to the questions?

Answer (score 1):

If you used custom fields to store answers for the questions than you can use Event Participants List( CiviCRM >> Reports >> Event reports) report to get all the information gathered for the event.

Note: Make sure you have is searchable option turned on for all the custom fields you need to be available on report or search.